# Kubuntu booted to a black screen and I had to restart sddm. Now the performance is super slow

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu

This all started when I switched to my Nvidia gt 750m in the Nvidia server settings. I started to play Kerbal Space Program and the screen,for lack of a better word, freaked the hell out. There was an obscene amount of screen tearing and artifacts. I was forced to restart and when I booted in it was to a black screen. I used tty to restart sddm and that brought the gui back. However, now, the performance is super slow and the idle cpu usage is almost always at 100%. To be clear, before this debacle, my performance was always smooth and idle cpu usage hovered around 1 or 2%. Is there anyway I can bring my performance back? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted a couple of hours later and it looks like the problem resolved itself.